# Navigation Control Problem

Tags: objective-c, navigation, controls

I am using some methods to load a new .xib and go back to the main menu.  However after about five time it crashes by using too much memory.  I need to be able to go back to the main menu and to the game many times.  Any other methods I should use for the navigation controls.

Main Menu part:

```
GameViewController* game = [[GameViewController alloc initWithNibName:@"GameViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:game animated:NO];
```

Game part to return to main menu:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Here is the viewdidLoad
{
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self StartTimer];

```
TotalSeconds = 0;
GameCenterTotalSeconds = 0;
timeSec = 0;
timeMin = 0;


Background = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)] autorelease];
Background.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[ [ NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Background" ofType:@"png"]];
[self.view addSubview:Background];


timeLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:timeLabel];


NumberLabel = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -4, 60, 70)] autorelease];
NumberLabel.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[ NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Number" ofType:@"png"]];
[self.view addSubview:NumberLabel];

QuestionNumber = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(23, 17, 20, 20)] autorelease];
QuestionNumber.text = @"1";
QuestionNumber.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
QuestionNumber.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[QuestionNumber setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:30]];
[self.view addSubview:QuestionNumber];

numberLives = 1;

appDelegate = (OppositeMoronTestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


musicButton = [[[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain] autorelease];
musicButton.frame = CGRectMake(5, 283, 35, 35);
musicButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

if (appDelegate.shouldPlayMusic == YES) {

    UIImage *Image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[ NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MusicOn" ofType:@"png"]];
    [musicButton setBackgroundImage:Image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [musicButton addTarget:self action:@selector(TurnMusicOff) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
} else {
    UIImage *Image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[ NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MusicOff" ofType:@"png"]];
    [musicButton setBackgroundImage:Image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [musicButton addTarget:self action:@selector(TurnMusicOn) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}


[self.view addSubview:musicButton];
[self showQuestion1];
```

}

}

Comment: Are you releasing `game` before you alloc it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `autorelease` on your view controller:

```
GameViewController* game = [[[GameViewController alloc initWithNibName:@"GameViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

The navigation controller will take ownership of the view controller passed to it, so you don't have to keep a reference to it. But you can't keep allocating GameViewControllers over and over without releasing them. `autorelease` is useful for that. You could also release it after you've passed it to the navigation controller if you prefer:

```
GameViewController* game = [[GameViewController alloc initWithNibName:@"GameViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:game animated:NO];
[game release];
game = nil;
```

EDIT:
So if you're already releasing the `game` object, then it must be a memory leak within the `GameViewController` class itself.

Annything you alloc, copy or retain in your `GameViewController` class you're supposed to release in the `dealloc` method (and maybe also in the `viewDidUnload` method if you're alloc/copy/retaining in the `viewDidLoad` method).

The [iOS Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) might be helpful if you want to get into more detail.

If you want to post the relevant code from the `GameViewController` class, I'm sure someone will be able to help you pin down the memory leak.

You can also try the Leaks tool in [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1)

EDIT 2:

I'm assuming you have several `IBOutlets` connected to properties in your `GameViewController` class...

don't know if you're already doing this, but in your `viewDidUnload` method AND on your `dealloc` method you have to set all of these `IBOutlets` properties to nil in order to release them, like so:

```
- viewDidUnload
{
    //... whatever comes before

    self.timeLabel = nil;
    self.NumberLabel  = nil;
    //... etc
}
- dealloc
{
    //... whatever comes before

    self.timeLabel = nil;
    self.NumberLabel  = nil;
    //... etc

    [super dealloc];
}
```

In general, if you have any properties declared with `retain`, that means that when you set that property the object will be retained. If you set that property to `nil`, the object that was there will be `released` for you. So any properties with the `retain` keyword should be set to `nil` (or the backing ivar released).

Comment: ok, you didn't post any part of your code where you release it... I think that would be relevant if you're having a memory leak problem. Can you post the part of the code immediately after the part you posted, where you release `game`?

Comment: then I assume it's a memory leak inside your `GameViewController` class. If you can edit your original question and post some of the relevant code from that class someone might be able to help.

Comment: oh, you shouldn't be calling removeFromSuperview if you're adding it to a navigation controller... the navigation controller will take care of doing the transitions and removing the views. But I don't think that would cause the leak anyway.

Comment: Don't when I return to the main menu it will release all of the memory used by the GameViewController class

Comment: Sorry the removeFromSuperview isn't the correct code.  I was testing out a different way of launching the view.  Both using the navigation controller and add and removing a view.

Comment: I don't have any IBOutlets.  However I have many objects declared.  Do I still ave to set then to nil even if I put all of the objects to autorelease.